# Android :Checking if audio is playing

Tags: android, audio

i need to check if sounds from my application are playing.

i found some code but its only checking if audio is playing at the start of the activity;

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(manager.isMusicActive())
         {
            //something
         }
```

Is there somekind of Listener?

Comment: how do you play audio?

Comment: The sound is from TexttoSpeech.

Now i have tried to solve my problem with a thread but in the end it could not solve my problems.
The best solution would be a Listener or something like that.